# TextBox.SelStart/SelLength and long strings

Tags: vba, ms-access, winapi

I have a form in an Access database (Access 2013). On this form is a `TextBox` where the user can enter text.
With the click of a button I'd like to do something with the text in the `TextBox` (like insert text). For that I use the properties
`SelStart` and `SelLength` of the `TextBox` to 
determine where to put my new text.

But unfortunately both properties (`SelStart` and `SelLength`) are VBA `Integer` values, that means, as long as the length of the text in my `TextBox` is below Integer.MaxValue (=32.767) `SelStart` is right, but as soon as I exceed Integer.MaxValue `SelStart` jumps zu Integer.MinValue (=-32.768) and count onwards from that number. So, if my text length is 40.000 then `SelStart` delivers -25.535.

Is there any way to get the correct values for `SelStart` and `SelLength` regardless of the length of the string? Maybe with an API function instead of the faulty Access properties?

Comment: If the value read is negative, you could add `+ 32767 + 32768` to the value. Of course, this will only work until you reach twice the maximum value of Integer. Otherwise, you may have to split such large text in chunks (in a subform).

Comment: I thought of calculating the correct value myself, but I don't want to implement something that is not working properly under any circumstances. That's why I still hope there's a solution using WinAPI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>Posting this as a separate answer because it's fully distinct</sub>

You can use the `SendMessage` WinAPI function with the `EM_GETSEL` constant to get the selection of the currently active control.

**Declarations:**

<sub>(since we're not working with strings, it doesn't matter if you use SendMessageA or SendMessageW, these declarations are VBA7 only)</sub>

```
Public Declare Function SendMessage Lib "User32.dll" Alias "SendMessageW" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal Msg As Integer, ByVal wParam As LongPtr, ByVal lParam As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Public Declare Function GetFocus Lib "User32.dll" () As LongPtr
Public Const EM_SETSEL As Integer = &HB1
Public Const EM_GETSEL As Integer = &HB0
```

Implement it:

```
Public Sub GetSelection()
    Dim StartSel As Long
    Dim EndSel As Long
    Dim hWnd As LongPtr
    hWnd = GetFocus
    SendMessage hWnd, EM_GETSEL, VarPtr(StartSel), VarPtr(EndSel)
    Debug.Print StartSel
    Debug.Print EndSel
End Sub
```

This prints the selection of the currently active control.

I've verified that for text boxes with a selection over the 32768th character, the result is the same as my first solution (`StartSel = UIntToLong(Control.SelStart)` = True, and `EndSel = UIntToLong(Control.SelStart + Control.SelLength)` is also true.

I recommend the other solution over this WinAPI solution, since this one uses the currently active control and gives no error if that's the wrong one, uses external API calls, and likely has a bit more overhead.

This solution does have support for textboxes with more than 2^16 characters, but Access behaves finicky if that happens and I recommend not using the built-in textbox control for such large textboxes.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like it's an unsigned integer.

VBA doesn't support unsigned types, so when the sign bit gets set (for a 2-byte integer, as soon as the value goes above (2^15)-1), it suddenly becomes negative. However, you can use the underlying functions to work with them.

I've written these functions to work with unsigned integers a while ago, you can use it to convert a long to an unsigned integer and back:

```
Public Function LongToUInt(lIn As Long) As Integer
    If lIn >= 2 ^ 16 Then Exit Function 'Overflow, might want to raise an error
    If lIn < 0 Then Exit Function 'Unsigned type doesn't support negatives, might want to raise an error
    If lIn > (2 ^ 15) - 1 Then 'Set sign bit, then store remainder in an integer
        LongToUInt = (-2 ^ 16) + lIn
    Else
        LongToUInt = lIn
    End If
End Function

Public Function UIntToLong(iIn As Integer) As Long
    'No checks, an UINT always fits inside a long
    If iIn < 0 Then
        UIntToLong = iIn + 2 ^ 16
    Else
        UIntToLong = iIn
    End If
End Function
```

Implement them:

```
Textbox.SelStart = LongToUInt(40000)

Dim theStart As Long
theStart = UIntToLong(Textbox.SelStart)
```

As Gustav noted, there's still a problem with an overflow if the value is larger than (2^16)-1 (the maximum value of an unsigned 2-byte integer)

Comment: An unsigned integer probably would work up to a length of 65.535, but since it's only working up to 32.767 it seems to be a signed integer that is getting unsigned integer values or long values internally.

Comment: @Nostromo VBA doesn't support unsigned integers. I've added a short clarification on what happens.